# Как записать в массив числа из тега input?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, html5

Здравствуйте, как записать в массив числа в теге `<input id="clck" type="text" value="">` разделенных запятыми? Допустим, пользователь ввел `12,12,4,6,7,9` - получилось 6 элементов массива, `b[0] = 12, b[1] = 12, ..., b[5]=9`. Из этого вытекает другой вопрос, верно ли я делаю используя setinterval() для изменения длины массива?

```
var a = document.getElementById("clck"), b = [];
function interval() {
  for(var i=0; i<a.value.length; i++);
   b[i] = ?? // тут запись
  ++count;
  if (count >= 500) clearInterval(intervalID);
}
var intervalID = setInterval(interval, 600);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Дано**: строка на входе со значениями разделенными запятыми.

**Решение**: использовать метод `split` для разделения строки на элементы массива по заданному разделителю (запятой).

> Источник: [split](http://javascript.ru/string/split)

---

`setInterval` вы используете совершенно не к месту, он нужен для других задач, где каким-либо действиям необходим временной интервал при выполнении.

```js
var inputVal,
    button = document.querySelector('button'),
    array = [];

button.addEventListener('click', function() {
  inputVal = document.querySelector('input').value;
  array = inputVal.split(',');
  
  console.log(array);
});
```

```html
<input value="" type="text" />
<button>to Array</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

Для того, чтобы разбить строку на массив по определенному разделителю используется метод `String.split()`

```
b = document.getElementById("clck").value.split(",");
```